# Run a SQL Script on a timer through DBVisualizer

Tags: mysql, sql

Using DBVisualizer is there any way to run a SQL Script or Command on a timer?

I am using MySQL

Answer (score 2):

One option is MySQL 5's events (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html)

```
CREATE EVENT event_name ON SCHEDULE EVERY 2 MINUTE DO <SQL query>
```

The other option is a scheduled task (cron in Linux).

Answer (score 0):

If run a job from [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) every two minutes, it means you wouldn't have to have this application loaded/running.